# How to colour lines of epoch.js chart?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

I'm pulling some data out of graphite, transforming it and using [epoch.js to display it as a realtime line chart](http://fastly.github.io/epoch/real-time/#line).

```
$('#graph').epoch({ 
    type: 'time.line', 
    data: data,
    axes: ['left', 'right', 'bottom']
});
```

This successfully displays the graph, but both the lines are black. The [graph in the epoch example](http://fastly.github.io/epoch/real-time/#line) has different colours for each line, but I can't find any reference of how to do this in the docs or work out how it is doing it from the example's source.

How can I change the colours of the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set colors layer per layer, this trick works:

https://github.com/epochjs/epoch/issues/137#issuecomment-177531945

```
var layer_num = 0  # insert here the number of the layer
var catname = "category2"  # insert here the css class category
chart.getVisibleLayers()[layer_num].className = "layer " + catname
```

[Visit this link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors) for more informations about category colors. By default, `category10` is used, so "category1" is `#1f77b4`, "category2" is `#ff7f0e` etc

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same issue and it took me quite some time before I realized what's wrong.

In my case I forgot to add class="epoch category10" to the div that has the graph in it. E.g.

```
<div id="area" class="epoch category10" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

It seems that the examples on the basic and real-time chart pages are missing this class definition. The getting started page however specifically states the above line.